# Using Qt classes with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, qt, memory

I am building a Qt 5 application. I would like to have all of my Qt objects which are pointers to be `unique_ptr` so I don't have to worry about calling `delete`.

My code (below) compiles. The issue is that, when I close the program, I hit a `static_assert` in the destructor of my main class `Interface`. The message is "can't delete an incomplete type" and in the watch window it appears that `QFlags<enum Qt::AlignmentFlag>` is not known in the destructor of `QGridLayout`. I am not sure why this would be - I can use `Qt::AlignmentFlag` in my main function, etc.

There are similar questions regarding `unique_ptr` with incomplete type on stack overflow. However, this seems to be a Qt specific issue (i.e. I'm not explicitly using forward declarations, etc. in my code). Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <memory>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QListView>
#include <QWidget>
#include <Qt>

class Interface
{
    std::unique_ptr<QMainWindow> mainWindow;
    std::unique_ptr<QListView> mainList;
    std::unique_ptr<QVBoxLayout> verticalLayout;
    std::unique_ptr<QGridLayout> mainLayout;
    std::unique_ptr<QWidget> mainWidget;

public:

    Interface()
    {
        mainWidget.reset(new QWidget());
        mainList.reset(new QListView());
        verticalLayout.reset(new QVBoxLayout());
        mainLayout.reset(new QGridLayout());
        mainWindow.reset(new QMainWindow());

        verticalLayout->addWidget(mainList.get());
        mainLayout->addLayout(verticalLayout.get(), 0, 0, 1, 1);
        mainWidget->setLayout(mainLayout.get());
        mainWindow->setCentralWidget(mainWidget.get());
        mainWindow->show();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Interface i;
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Qt also handles memory, so you have to delete widget in right order. (So order of member is really important).

Comment: You might so have double deletion.

Comment: Could you give an example of what I should do differently in my code so the order is correct?

Comment: If I'm correct, members order should be: `mainWindow`, `mainWidget`, `mainLayout`, `verticalLayout`, `mainList`.

Comment: Not sure what is discussed here but for Qt widgets we should rather pass the 'parent' to dynamically allocated child. Not saying that that is the only way to develop the app with widgets but you have to understand the widget lifecycle better to use the scoped pointer. Just look at Qt examples and try to reproduce them.

Comment: If it is all about worrying about calling delete, you'll end up having much more worries about the right order as noted by @Jarod42. Qt naturally has these `QObject`/`QWidget` trees where a parent is responsible to delete all its children when it gets destructed. In your class, it might be a better idea to hold a smart pointer to the root of the tree (i.e. `mainWindow` in your code) and let it manage its children's lifetime as it would normally do. Or even better, just use automatic allocation for your `mainWindow`...

Comment: These are all very useful comments - thanks

Comment: It is unfortunate that Qt interfaces use regular pointers for ownership transfer :-/